# Configuring struct receivers to use a certain type

Tags: go, model

I noticed whilst writing some RESTful endpoints in Lambda, I had three models, and the handlers, were all identical. They take a request, fetch some data from a repository, and return the data as a response. The only thing which differed in each handler function, was the model instance. So I was thinking of ways of passing in the type and re-using the same functionality for marshalling the response into JSON etc.

If I have a pattern such as this:

```
type Handler struct {
  model interface{}
  repository
}

func (h *Handler) Fetch(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
  model := h.model
  if err := h.repository.Fetch(id, &model); err != nil {
    return ErrResponse(err, http.StatusInternalServerError)
  }
  return Response(map[string]interface{}{
    "resource": model,
  }, http.StatusOK)
}
```

Then calling this:

```
repository := NewRepository(tableName, connection)
handler := &helpers.Handler{repository, new(models.Client)}
```

I'm re-assigning `model := h.model` so that the struct itself doesn't become 'stateful', otherwise I'd have to worry about locking to ensure its thread safe. So I figured I could just re-assign it in the scope of the handler to avoid that.

This pattern seems to work okay, but I wondered if there were any potential downsides or pitfalls?

Comment: The struct contains fields. Fields are state. It is stateful. Also note that if `model` is filled with a pointer, your local assignment copies the pointer and you can still encounter race conditions.

Comment: @Adrian so, as long as I don't pass in a pointer to the handler struct, as the model, I should be okay? This approach feels like an anti-pattern, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Yes. However in your example code, you are passing a pointer (`new` creates a pointer).

Comment: Or I guess it looks like you're trying to but your order of fields is maybe backwards? Unless `repository` is your model and `models.Client` is your repository?